# Add SWF file to wordpress through custom template

Tags: uploads, media, media-library

I am trying to attach an swf file to my website. I have that swf file in my local system. But wordpress is not alowing me to upload the swf file into the media library. I want to add that swf to my homepage which have a specific custom template. I want to add the swf file through this template file rather than the editor. Is there anyway for that?

Comment: These are different questions, and we should only ask one per Question. For one, research for "mime-types" or "allowed extensions" here. For the other, [check this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/115163).

Answer (score 1):

**wordpress is not alowing me to upload the swf file into the media library**

Actually you can insert this code to the functions.php:

```
add_filter('upload_mimes', 'add_custom_upload_mimes');
function add_custom_upload_mimes($existing_mimes){
    $existing_mimes['swf'] = 'text/swf'; //allow swf files
    return $existing_mimes;
}
```

Then you try to upload your swf file to the media library.

As for homepage, you can install a plugin, [Ultimate TinyMCE](http://wordpress.org/plugins/ultimate-tinymce/). Copy the file url from media library and paste to the homepage by searching for a button "insert/edit embedded media" and click "insert".

I think you will be able to get what you want.